# Visualize results from vehicle routing in CPLEX

Tags: optimization, graph, mathematical-optimization, cplex, vehicle-routing

currently I am solving vehicle routing problems using CPLEX.
I am using Excel as a data source for the model.
I also write the solution value of the decision variable x into my Excel sheet.

My goal is to present the solution like this:

[image]

A graph showing the positions of the depot and customers based on their coordinates and the routes that have been constructed in the solution process.

How could I do this? Which software enables such graphs?
I don't think CPLEX has any build-in solutions for this, but maybe I can do it in Excel?

Comment: Geogebra is a good tool to display nodes and directed arcs. You can import x and y coordinates from excel into Geogebra and have it display those objects.

Comment: Could you elaborate how that works or link me to any sites/videos that help explaining it? Just downloaded the tool and played around with it without much success.

Comment: Does this help? https://help.geogebra.org/topic/difficulty-importing-tab-delimited-file-into-geogebra-spreadsheet#comment-292726 Geogebra technical support provides a video snapshot of how to import x and y coordinates into Geogebra.

Comment: Try https://graphviz.org/